# dispatch is not a function error when changed from mapDispatchToProps to mergeProps?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I need in state in mapDispatchToProps,
So, I found that need to substitute mapDispatchToProps with mergeProps function.
Was

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    load: () => dispatch(actions.loadProjects()),
  };
}
```

Changed to

```
function mergeProps(stateProps, dispatchProps) {
  const {dispatch} = dispatchProps;

  return {
    load: () => dispatch(actions.loadProjects()),
  };
}
```

and connect changed from

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ViewComponent);
```

to

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mergeProps)(ViewComponent);
```

But there is error message **dispatch is not a function**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function mergeProps(stateProps, dispatchProps) {

  return {
    load: () => dispatchProps.loadProjects(),
  };
}
```

Comment: dispatchProps.loadProjects is not a function